# Многопоточность выполнения функции

Tags: node.js, faq

Есть функция, которую хотелось бы запустить в 10-20 экземплярах одновременно.
Чтобы одновременно все экземпляры проработали и вернули значение.

Как это можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Многопоточность NodeJS на примере выполнения ф-ии n раз.

JS - однопоточен.

Много экземпляров JS - много потоков.

Worker/WebWorker - новый экземпляр JS.

### Содержание

- Доки
- Код
- Вывод
- Комментарии к коду

### Доки

nodejs:

- https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

для веба:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

тестовая ф-я для загрузки CPU:

- https://gist.github.com/sqren/5083d73f184acae0c5b7

Promise

- https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise
- https://learn.javascript.ru/promise
- https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

### Код

```
const os = require('os')
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')

const cpuCount = os.cpus().length
console.log({ cpuCount })


const repeat = (q = 0, f = () => { }, arr = []) => {
    arr.push(f())
    if (--q) { repeat(q, f, arr) }
    return arr
}

T2: {
    /**@type {Promise<string>[]} */
    const arr = repeat(cpuCount, () => evalInWorkerP(stressTestCPU))
    Promise.all(arr).then(messList => {
        messList.forEach(m => console.log('  T2', m))
    })
}

T1: {
    /**@type {Promise<string>[]} */
    const arr = repeat(cpuCount, () => evalInWorkerP(stressTestCPU))
    arr.forEach(p => {
        p.then(m => {
            console.log('T1', m)
        })
    })
}


/**
 * 
 * @param {Function} f 
 * @param {string} fName 
 */
function evalInWorkerP(f, fName = f.name || 'foo') {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        try {
            const w = evalInWorker(f, fName)
            const id = w.threadId
            // w.on('exit', i => console.log(`exit_${id}`))
            w.on('error', e => { rej(e) })
            w.on('message', m => {
                const message = `message_${id}: ${m}`
                res(message)
                // console.log(message)
            })
        } catch (error) {
            rej(error)
        }
    })
}

/**
 * 
 * @param {Function} f 
 * @param {string} fName 
 */
function evalInWorker(f, fName = f.name || 'foo') {
    var w = new Worker(`
            const { parentPort } = require('worker_threads')
            const ${fName} = ${f.toString()};
            const message = ${fName}();
            parentPort.postMessage(message)
        `, { eval: true })
    return w
}
test: {
    break test;
    const w = evalInWorker(() => 'test message')
    w.on('message', m => { console.log('message:', m) })
}


function stressTestCPU() {
    let message = null
    MAIN: {
        const repeat = {
            tSec: 0,
            maxSec: 5,
            ch(_t) {
                this.tSec += _t
                // console.log(`${this.t.toFixed(2)} сек.`)
                return this.tSec < this.maxSec
            }
        }
        const t = mySlowFunction(repeat)
        message = `${t.toFixed(4)} сек.`
    }
    return message
    // ---------------------------------------------------
    /** @param {{
        ch(_t: number): boolean;
    }} repeat */
    function mySlowFunction(repeat) {
        const baseNumber = 10
        let start = Date.now()
        let result = 0
        for (var i = Math.pow(baseNumber, 7); i >= 0; i--) {
            result += Math.atan(i) * Math.tan(i);
        }
        let t = (Date.now() - start) / 1000
        if (repeat && repeat.ch(t)) {
            t += mySlowFunction(repeat)
        }
        return t
    }
}
```

### Вывод

```bsh
{ cpuCount: 8 }
T1 message_10: 5.8560 сек.
T1 message_16: 5.8330 сек.
T1 message_14: 6.2160 сек.
T1 message_13: 6.3720 сек.
T1 message_12: 6.3130 сек.
T1 message_15: 6.3630 сек.
T1 message_9: 6.4510 сек.
T1 message_11: 6.4910 сек.
  T2 message_1: 6.2100 сек.
  T2 message_2: 6.5180 сек.
  T2 message_3: 6.3620 сек.
  T2 message_4: 6.3990 сек.
  T2 message_5: 6.1920 сек.
  T2 message_6: 6.3650 сек.
  T2 message_7: 6.1390 сек.
  T2 message_8: 6.3950 сек.
```

### Комментарии к коду

- `cpuCount` - количество потоков(не ядер) процессора.
- `repeat` - вспомогательная ф-я (повторение).
- `stressTestCPU` - тестовая ф-я для загрузки CPU.

Comment: Прошу прощения. У вас вызывается одна и та же функция 8 раз. Не подскажете, как запустить воркер для разных заданий? 
Вот более подробно по вопросу: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094318/Обработка-многомерного-массива-с-помощью-worker-threads