# Многопоточность в мобильном Chrome - как посмотреть нагрузку по веб-воркерам и ядрам?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, tensorflow, webworkers

Написал простую систему видеонаблюдения с распознаванием людей на чистом JavaScript. Работу с нейросетью засунул в отдельный тред (воркер), а собственно видеозапись ведется в главном треде. Идеально работает в Chrome под линуксом даже на древнем 2-х ядерном железе. А на относительно новом 4-х ядерном андроид-телефоне в момент работы нейросети подвисает и главный тред, то есть начинает лагать пользовательский интерфейс !

Как посмотреть в хроме - сколько воркеров запущено, как они распределены по ядрам, и где основные задержки ?

PS
Все приложенение написано на async/await, главный тред нигде не блокируется, в воркер передается всего один видеокадр (массив пикселей), тормоза начинаются именно в момент распознавания. Может быть TensorFlow как-то странно процессор использует или встроенную видеокарту (хотя, в ноуте тоже встроенная).

[Работающее демо](https://balajahe.github.io/cctv_nn/)

[Репозитарий с кодом](https://github.com/balajahe/balajahe.github.io/tree/master/cctv_nn)

[Собственно воркер с нейросетью](https://github.com/balajahe/balajahe.github.io/blob/master/cctv_nn/video-detector.js)

[А вот главный тред с вызовом воркера](https://github.com/balajahe/balajahe.github.io/blob/master/cctv_nn/video-recorder.js)

Буду благодарен за любые идеи !

Comment: Что бы найти узкое место, отключайте функции и тестируйте. Отключите отрисовку на канвасе, отключите распознавание, протестируйте время передачи данных в воркер. Узкое место надо локализовать сначала, а потом уже исправлять. В данном виде вопрос слишком общий и вряд ли кто-то сможет дать адекватный ответ, вида *В файле **video-recorder.js** в строке #76 ошибка*.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо, это понятно, я просто думал что у Хрома есть такие инструменты. Со стороны линукса я могу смотреть загрузку тредов, и там все нормально, а в хроме и мобильных ОС я не силен к сожалению. Выглядит так, что тормозит вызов 
await model.detect(ev.data)
но что внутри делает TensolFlow для меня загадка, может она там кучу тредов создает, или захватывает видеокарту (что скорее всего). Попробую хромный профайлер поковырять...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Буду благодарен за любые идеи !

---

> Как посмотреть в хроме - сколько воркеров запущено?

см. раздел release note

> Как они распределены по ядрам?

На сколько я знаю:
Новый воркер - новый поток "ядро".

Но я не знаю как оно разруливается если их больше "ядер".
В мысле оно работает, но максимальная производительность если их столько же сколько потоков поддерживает процессор.
Ещё вопрос с ситуацией когда есть "большие" и "малые" ядра.

> Где основные задержки ?

- ,-

### ядра

1. Ядра на PC и "мобильные" - не одно и то же.
2. Ядра даже внутри одного процессора могут быть разные.
3. Смотреть нужно не ядра а потоки, т.к. на ядро их может быть более одного.

### Тест

Начните с написания тестового примера, для наблюдения как оно работает, грузит процессор.

[Там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1091956/232932) есть код для ноды (правда его нужно немного переписать)

### release note (что нового) от 2018/01

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools

  - [Надежный кодовый шаг с рабочими и асинхронный код](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#stepping)
  - [Несколько записей в панели Performance](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#recordings)

### Get Started with Remote Debugging Android Devices

- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

### Загрузка процессора.

Загрузку по ядрам(потокам) хром не умеет даже на PC -> нужно использовать системные утилиты.

- AnTuTu (программа для телефона)

или

- https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler?hl=en

### Проверка поддержки webgl.

- https://get.webgl.org/

я не в курсе нужен ли он в tensorflowJS но [там](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/?hl=ru) -> "News & announcements" они что-то говорят про "WebGL acceleration"

> We have launched the alpha version of first-class React Native support for TF.js, including WebGL acceleration on supported platforms. Learn how to bring performant ML into your React Native app.

### 1.нативный и 2.не очень код

1. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/?hl=ru
2. react-native - https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-react-native

Comment: Исчерпывающе ! Проверил WebGL, он конечно есть, иначе бы вообще ничего не работало, а за помощь по хрому, и остальные ссылки - огромное спасибо, ушел читать !

Comment: да, нунжно найти/написать код который получает что-то вроде этой информации => страница `chrome://gpu/` Graphics Feature Status -> Canvas: Hardware accelerated. на телефоне тоже работает. список всех страниц - `chrome://chrome-urls/` (правда я не знаю на сколько это важно в контексте вопроса)