# Асинхронность в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, асинхронность

Бьюсь головой об стену с пониманием асинхронности.

- Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли добиться асинхронности в JS не используя таймеры (setTimeout)?
- По идее это же та самая нить, потянув за которую мы можем написать асинхронный код?
- И я так понимаю написание колбэков без использования таймера не целесообразно, ведь потеряется асинхронность?

Можете привести пример асинхронного кода без использования таймеров, промисов и тд?

Comment: [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) и [async/await](https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await), про связь колбеков и таймеров не совсем понял, что имеется ввиду.

Comment: Таймер выполняет некую функцию через `заранее заданный и определенный`  промежуток времени. Асинхронность подразумевает не определяемое заранее срабатывание того, или иного кода/функции, то есть некое действие может выполниться в любой, не известный заранее, момент, или даже не выполниться вовсе

Comment: Перечитал ваш вопрос, если вы ищете подобие Thread в JS, то можете заглянуть сюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036/javascript-and-threads Но там в основном сказано тоже самое, что озвучили в вопросе и вы.

Comment: Что ты понимаешь под асинхронностью?

Comment: если threads - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1091898/232932

Comment: @Grundy, пока одна часть кода выполняется, другая его часть не останавливается и продолжает свое выполнение

Comment: @Torin_21, это ты скорее параллельно выполнение описал (считай много многопоточность) это не связано с асинхронностью и в яваскрипте такого нет. Максимум - web worker

Answer (score 1):

Таймеры - это просто пример асинхронного вызова. Есть синхронное выполнение - когда ждут результата выполнения какой-либо функции, прежде чем начинать другую работу. А есть асинхронное, когда соответственно не ждут, и начинают делать, что-то еще